# ngModel doesn't work even after adding formsModule and ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: angular

app.module.ts:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

 imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
HttpClientModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
],
```

register.component.ts:

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
public author = new Author();
constructor() {}

ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

register.component.html

```
<input type="text" name="first" id="first" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="author.first_name">
```

Even after import all that, the ngModel still doesn't work.
Thanks for the helpers!!

Comment: FormsModule should be imported to the same module as the one where `RegisterComponent` is registered

Comment: it is imported to the same module, i just connected all the details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are importing the modules in wrong way as you showed in you code in app.module.ts file. It should be like

```
@NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
declarations: [AppComponent],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Finally, I have a solution for you. I have imported both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule in my app.module file and used your code. It worked for me.

Please Check the Link: [Stackblitz Solution Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/input-ngmodel-er7bak?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

**Note:** Check the app.module.ts and app.component.ts files. I hope that it will be helpful for you.

Comment: I did exactly as the link you send, but it is still doesn't work. maybe there is another solution?

Comment: It is working perfectly in the link. Do you checked the link's output. If the code inside link is working but not working in your project then I anticipate something went wrong in your project. Because the same code is working in stackblitz and in my pc too. Can you create a stackblitz demo with same problem?

Comment: I did it in another project and it worked, i think the problem it is not ngModel, thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for all the helpers. I fixed the problem, the problem was that my Angular Language service wasn't update. now i have updated it and now everything working fine.

[what i update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsN91.png)